# Data splitting strategies for time series datasets

Tags: time-series, train-test-split

I would require some help in terms of data split to evaluate and test multiple algorithms for time series segmentation. For example, let's take [Physionet ECG LUDB dataset](https://physionet.org/content/ludb/1.0.1/). This dataset consist of 200 patients recordings and each recording is of 10 sec (roughly 7-8 ecg cycles per recording). Our task is to segment these ecg cycles. Now, to test an unsupervised algorithm I need to split this time series database into train and test. I want to use train dataset to tune algorithm parameter. And then run algorithm on test dataset for evaluation. Now, I am not able to decide on how to get a good representative training set. Few option I thought are:

1. Do stratified sampling and divide patients among train and test set based on demographics. Assumption is that if our train set contains patients with different age, sex or disease type then we can cover most of ecg cycle variations.
2. Segment each 200 time series into a split of X% train and Y% test. Example first 4 consecutive cycles train and next 4 consecutive cycles test.

I did some google searches but I didn't find any helpful material. I request SO users for some guide, any links or useful published paper which explains different approaches for time series segmentation data split strategies.

Comment: Ultimately, ask yourself what do you want to achieve? If you will have new patients and your model will have to infer on them, it's better to do 1. If you can always get some data of the patients before you need to make an inference, you can always retrain the model every time and 2 might be better.

Comment: @PhilippeRemy Intersting. Thanks for this input. Never thought in this direction..